# Merging and sorting overlapped intervals

Tags: c#

We are given an array of intervals we need to merge all overlapping intervals and sort the resulting non-overlapping intervals. When they "touch" in a single point, intervals are *also* considered to be overlapping .

```
class Span
{
    public uint Start { get; }
    public uint End { get; }

    private Span(uint start, uint end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    private static Span _default = new Span(0, 0);

    // To avoid constructor throwing an exception
    public static Span Create(uint start, uint end)
    {
        if (start > end) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(start), "Begin cannot me more than end");
        return new Span(start, end);
    }

    public bool IsOverlapped(Span other)
    {
        return Start <= other.End && End >= other.Start;
    }

    public Span Merge(Span other)
    {
        if (!IsOverlapped(other)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(other), "Spans must overlap");
        return new Span(Math.Min(Start, other.Start), Math.Max(End, other.End));
    }

    public bool TryMerge(Span other, out Span mergedItem)
    {
        mergedItem = _default;
        if (!IsOverlapped(other)) return false;
        mergedItem = new Span(Math.Min(Start, other.Start), Math.Max(End, other.End));
        return true;
    }
}

// In reality this method will be in a different class where it belongs
class Util
{
    public static Span[] Normalise(Span[] spans)
    {
        var results = new List<Span>();
        foreach (var item in spans.OrderBy(x => x.Start))
        {
            var lastResultIndex = results.Count - 1;
            if (lastResultIndex >= 0 && results[lastResultIndex].TryMerge(item, out Span mergedItem))
            {
                results[lastResultIndex] = mergedItem;
            }
            else
            {
                results.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return results.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the point in having the `Create` method here, there's no reason why a constructor can't throw an exception in C#. I'd just get rid of `Create` and move it all into the constructor (making it public).

The name `IsOverlapped` sounds a bit odd to me. `Is` is present tense and `Overlapped` is past tense. Maybe something like `IsOverlapping` or even just `Overlaps`.

You have a typo here: "Begin cannot me more than end". `me` should be `be`.

If you have access to expression-bodied members, they can reduce noise IMO:

```
public bool Overlaps(Span other) => other != null && Start <= other.End && End >= other.Start;
```

You'll notice that I've also put a null check for `other` in there at the same time.

You should rewrite `Merge` to call `TryMerge` internally:

```
public Span Merge(Span other) => 
    TryMerge(other, out var mergedSpan)
        ? mergedSpan
        : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(other), "Spans must overlap");
```

I really value conciseness and I'm happy with throw expressions so I like this kind of pattern. If you don't, this version would also be fine:

```
public Span Merge(Span other)
{
    if (!TryMerge(other, out var mergedSpan))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(other), "Spans must overlap");
    return mergedSpan;
}
```

Note: there's no need to check for null here as we now do that in `Overlaps`.

Your `Normalise` method looks good to me. It's a simple algorithm and easy to read.